# one sample word from each group

Tags: sanskrit

I am trying to collect one sample word from each group of अजन्त

Is this list correct?

```
अकारान्त    नपुसकलिंग   फल
अकारान्त    पुल्लिंग    राम
आकारान्त    पुल्लिंग    गोपा
आकारान्त    स्त्रीलिंग  बालिका
इकारान्त    पुल्लिंग    पति
इकारान्त    स्त्रीलिंग  मति
इकारान्त    नपुसकलिंग   वारि
ईकारान्त    स्त्रीलिंग  नदी
उकारान्त    पुल्लिंग    गुरु
उकारान्त    स्त्रीलिंग  धेनु
उकारान्त    नपुसकलिंग   मधु
ऊकारान्त    स्त्रीलिंग  वधू
ऊकारान्त    पुल्लिंग    स्वयंभू
ऋकारान्त    नपुसकलिंग   दातृ
ऋकारान्त    पुल्लिंग    पितृ
ऋकारान्त    स्त्रीलिंग  मातृ
ऐकारान्त    नपुसकलिंग   प्ररै
ऐकारान्त    स्त्रीलिंग  रै
ओकारान्त    पुल्लिंग    गो
ओकारान्त    नपुसकलिंग   प्रद्यो
औकारान्त    पुल्लिंग    ग्लौ
औकारान्त    स्त्रीलिंग  नौ
औकारान्त    नपुसकलिंग   सुनौ
```

Or am I missing anything?